# Firefox input goes out of the box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

The problem is probably related to bootstrap itself. When the input is wrapped into `col-*` class and is part of the `.form-inline` group, it goes out of the box.

Here is a quick test case:

```
<div class="form-inline row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
    <input class="form-control" id="qty-0" max="100" maxlength="3" min="1" value="1" type="number">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cudf4vh4/1/).

**Please note**: I am not looking for the fixes as it can be fixed by adding `width: 100%` as in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/cudf4vh4/2/).

Is this a bug in Firefox or expected behaviour?

**EDIT**: here is how the input appears 
[image: screenshot]

**EDIT 2**: to avoid confusion of wrongly used bootstrap classes [here is another example](https://jsfiddle.net/cudf4vh4/3/)

**EDIT 3**: [none bootstrap example replicating the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/cudf4vh4/4/)

Comment: Works fine in my firefox

Comment: Kindly share your firefox version

Comment: Works fine in firefox

Comment: Firefox version 54.0

Comment: You are mixing a `form-inline` with a `row`. `form-inline` must be put on a form` tag and contains `form-group`s instead of `row`s

Comment: @Morpheus I just tried with same version.. still not getting any issue

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ it is just an example. The `.form-inline` tag is added in the correct place on my project.

Comment: @Morpheus So why are you sharing a different code ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ to show a minimal code required for bug recreation.

Comment: @Morpheus As far as i can see, other comments shows that they cannot reproduce with the code you shared.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question - did you guys resize the window to around `820px`?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
input,
select {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: I know it will help. Can you explain why it is happening?

Comment: Because in select there is default padding and width: 100%
The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding means: 100% + padding so select goes out.

In this case you can set box-sizing: border-box too. 
https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: I already told you that I know that setting width will sort the problem. Please compare my example in Chrome and Firefox when the input width is auto. Chrome expands input to the width of the parent element, but Firefox isn't. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="form-control" id="qty-0" max="100" maxlength="3" min="1" value="1" type="number"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><span>Some text</span></div>
</div>
```

Edited:

Looking at your code, you are using form-inline, you can remove that part does not go with row for bootstrap as it is not compatible when using firefox or IE

Comment: I will ignore your answer as I don't need a solution, read the question again.

Comment: Take a look at the third example in the updated question.